# Font awesome not working server

Tags: html, css, icons, localhost, font-awesome

hello awesome font style icon sets on the web site using the icons at the local level, but I look at, but the server does not appear when.

[image]

Comment: Show css, HTML. Are you using `fa fa-icon-name` or just `fa-icon-name`? Second one from docs is wrong.

Comment: When I'm working on at the local server does not work

Comment: So is it your server not working or Font Awesome icons?

Comment: When working at my computer, but the server does not work
http://selahattinyuksel.net/site

Answer (score 9, accepted):

Are you declaring for UTF-8 in your document as well as in your stylesheet?

```
<meta charset="UTF-8">
```

or

```
<meta http-equiv="Content-Type" content="text/html;charset=UTF-8">
```

and in stylesheet (note, must be first line, first col):

```
@charset "utf-8";
```

## or

Font Awesome into your website with a single line of code. You don't even have to download or install anything!

Paste the following code into the  section of your site's HTML.

```
<link href="//maxcdn.bootstrapcdn.com/font-awesome/4.1.0/css/font-awesome.min.css" rel="stylesheet">
```

Most likely the actual font files are not being found. If you look in the font awesome CSS file you will probably see something like:

```
 @font-face {
      font-family: 'FontAwesome';
      src: url('../font/fontawesome-webfont.eot');
    }
```

Answer (score 1):

Add this to your web.config:

```
<system.webServer>
<staticContent>
  <remove fileExtension=".svg" />
  <remove fileExtension=".eot" />
  <remove fileExtension=".woff" />
  <remove fileExtension=".woff2" />
  <mimeMap fileExtension=".svg" mimeType="image/svg+xml" />
  <mimeMap fileExtension=".eot" mimeType="application/vnd.ms-fontobject" />
  <mimeMap fileExtension=".woff" mimeType="application/font-woff" />
  <mimeMap fileExtension=".woff2" mimeType="application/font-woff2" />
</staticContent>
system.webServer>
```